# Cannot find production.css during the build process in JavaScript MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, build, javascriptmvc

I generated a sample app just to test the build process and it errors out during the build process.

```
$ ./js steal/buildjs apps/hello/hello.html -to apps/helloprod
Building to apps/helloprod/

BUILDING STYLES --------------- 
   apps/hello/hello.css

STYLE BUNDLE > apps/helloprod/production.css
Nice! Compressed: 17.1%  Before: 41.0 bytes  After: 34.0 bytes
!!!!!!!!!!! ERROR !!!!!!!!!!!

-message       = java.io.FileNotFoundException: apps/helloprod/production.css (No such file or directory)
-fileName      = steal/rhino/file.js
-lineNumber    = 217
-name          = JavaException
-javaException = java.io.FileNotFoundException: apps/helloprod/production.css (No such file or directory)

                 error loading html element  [object HTMLScriptElement]   JavaException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: apps/helloprod/production.css (No such file or directory)
```

There was some content in .css file by default when I generated an app, so I even tried to remove the content inside (in which case it would error out because it cannot calculate the size of the file, eg. it was saying `NaN undefined` instead of 41.0 bytes). This particular error came up when I just had this in `hello.css`:

```
body{
  background-color:lightyellow;
}
```

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, according to the error message, that `apps/helloprod/production.css` file is missing.

Make sure that this file exists or remove if from the build process.

EDIT:

Is it because `steal/rhino/file.js` is included as a source file for CSS?

Comment: Well, this is the file the build process should create. It IS missing before the build process started, because it should be created during the build. See the line where it says: `STYLE BUNDLE > apps/helloprod/production.css`